# Vercel Blob Stored images are corrupted

Tags: node.js, image, rest, vercel

I am getting into using Vercel Blob to store images. I managed to successfully upload files by simply following the tutorial, deploying an API and making a POST request via Postman.

Interestingly enough any type of file is uploaded successfully, and so I can download them via Vercel web interface. However, only png/jpg/jpeg files seem corrupted as they can not be opened once downloaded, unlike pdf and other types, which works just fine.

```
app.post('/upload', async (_req: Request) => {
  const request: Request = _req;
  await handler(request);
})

// Works for PDFs when Postman is in form-data and Value has the PDF file
// Does not work for images
export async function handler(request: Request): Promise<NextResponse> {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const filename = searchParams.get('filename');

  const blob = await put(filename, request, {
    access: 'public'  
  });

  return NextResponse.json(blob);
}
```

As you can see piece of code has nothing special. So here it is the NodeJS request as output from Postman:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': '<remote>/upload',
  'headers': {
  },
  formData: {
    '': {
      'value': fs.createReadStream('/home/.../Downloads/tiny_spaces.png'),
      'options': {
        'filename': 'tiny_spaces.png',
        'contentType': null
      }
    }
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

Any idea on why this works well for most files, but corrupts images type files? Tips for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out.

So it had nothing to do with Vercel, as I expected, but all to do with the way the request is being formulated by Postman:

```
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': '<placeholder>/upload?filename=12345.png',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  },
  body: "<file contents here>"

};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

All in all, files should be attached to the binary option when defining the Body of your request in Postman.